# Magento 2 static deploy en_US argument invalid on XAMPP

Tags: magento2, cli, static-content

I've cloned a working magento 2 repo, done composer install and when I'm trying do do: setup:static-content:deploy I get the error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
en_US argument has invalid value, please run info:language:list for list of available locales
```

When I run info:language:list I've got an empty list.

This is happening only on windows with xampp - on other computer with linux/mac everything is working fine.

What could be the problem?

**EDIT:**
Every new install of magento 2 fails on two computers with win7 and xampp. I've tried wamp but it failed as well. It doesn't matter how magento is installed - though composer, git clone or zip package. Any ideas?

Comment: i also same problem on ubuntu lamp , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34054617/magento-2-installing-language-packs-nl-nl-translation?rq=1 not hlep me , if got solution update here

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `var/*` of magento2 and recompile all again by execute command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`. If problems still there you should re-install magento 
Latest version 2.0.2 [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/download)

Comment: The first thing I tried was removing var/* but it did not help. Reinstalling magento is not a solution for me at the moment. Any other ideas?

Comment: Backup db and try to install clean. Have you try to download full code i already answer above? Install new may help to solve conflict or missing packages. I don't have experience about this problem. My case works fine with Windows 10 and xampp install along with full zip source code

Comment: Every new install of magento 2 fails on two computers with win7 and xampp. I've tried wamp but it failed as well. It doesn't matter how magento is installed - though composer, git clone or zip package. Any ideas?

Comment: you should download from previous link in comment. I have tested in windows 10 + xampp. I works fine in latest release. Make sure you install version with sample data.
By the way , you should make sure to check all files you have changed. Maybe it contain error or typo issues may cause your problem